# Create Javascript Debugger

Tags: javascript, debugging, v8

I want to create my own javascrip debugger using V8 debugger in eclipse. But i am not getting any document about the V8 debugger or any Source code for v8 debugger. i have my own browser. i want to create one Javascript debugger which debug the .js code remotely. And same debugger i want connet with my own browser. So what can i use for creating debugger in eclipse. can i use v8 debugger as base for my debugger or any other idea i have to use for that.

Thanks for your support

Answer (score 0):

Just out of curiosity - why reinvent the bicycle? FireBug has arguably the best free javascript debugger available

Comment: Actually i have creatred my own Emulator for mobile which is completely browser based. so want create one Javascript debugger for that in eclipse i dont want to use firefox or anything else. i have my own browser thats why i want to create my own debugger. so please help me for that. can i use V8 debugger for that.